# Pass File Name to Input Text with Cloned Element

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I need to pass the name of file that i've selected in Input type=file with cloned element

here the preview img:

[image]

nah the 'CLONE' function is already work, but as i said, im stuck at pass the name of file from the input-type file

the filename should be stored inside the input nonroutine_expenses_file_name (left side of input button)

i've done with it but after i click the file from the file selector, its only pass to the first row, is anything wrong with my code?

my error :
[image]

here my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nonroutine_expenses_file_button').each(function() {
    var var_this = $(this);
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var_this.prev().click();
    });
  })

  $('.nonroutine_expenses_file').each(function() {
    var var_this = $(this);
    $(this).on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        var var_filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
        var_this.parent().parent().find('.nonroutine_expenses_file_name').val(var_filename);
      }
    });
  })

  var count = 1;
  $('#addMoreNonroutineExpenses').on('click', function() {
    console.log("count = " + count);

    var lastRow = $("#NonroutineExpenses-table tr").last().find(".sortNonroutineExpenses").val();
    console.log("lastRow = " + lastRow);
    if (lastRow == null) {
      lastRow = 0;
    }
    lastRow++;
    var table = $("#NonroutineExpenses-table");
    var original = $("#NonroutineExpenses-table tr:eq(1)");
    var clone = original.clone(true).appendTo("#NonroutineExpenses-table");
    newRow = clone.attr('class', 'clone');
    newRow.find("input").val("");
    newRow.find(".sortNonroutineExpenses").val(lastRow);
    count++;
  });

  $('#deleteNonroutineExpenses').on('click', function() {
    if (count > 1) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      count--;
      console.log("count = " + count);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive mt-4">
  <table class="table table-borderless" style="font-size: 13px;" id="NonroutineExpenses-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="align-middle text-left px-3 border-0" width="">Pengeluaran</th>
        <th class="align-middle text-left px-3" width="">Rincian Pengeluaran</th>
        <th class="align-middle text-left px-3" width="">Total Pengeluaran</th>
        <th class="align-middle text-left px-3" width="">Bukti Bayar</th>
        <th class="align-middle text-left px-3" width=""></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="text-secondary">
        <td class="align-middle text-left border-0 py-2 d-none">
          <input type="number" name="sortNonroutineExpenses[]" value="1" class="sortNonroutineExpenses border-0 text-center shadow-none font-weight-bold w-100" min="1" max="10" style="background-color: transparent;" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-left py-2">
          <input type="text" name="nonroutine_expenses[]" value="" class="employee_loan_amount drml-bg-lightgray border-0 p-2 drml-border-radius-4 w-100" placeholder="Jenis Pengeluaran">
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-left py-2">
          <input type="text" name="nonroutine_expenses_detail[]" value="" class="employee_loan_amount drml-bg-lightgray border-0 p-2 drml-border-radius-4 w-100" placeholder="Detail Pengeluaran">
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-left py-2">
          <input type="number" name="nonroutine_expenses_cost[]" value="" class="employee_loan_amount drml-bg-lightgray border-0 p-2 drml-border-radius-4 w-100" placeholder="0">
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-left py-0">
          <div class="drml-bg-lightgray drml-border-radius-4 px-2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" name="nonroutine_expenses_file_name[]" id="" class="bg-transparent mt-2 shadow-none border-0 outline-none nonroutine_expenses_file_name" style="width: 85px;" placeholder="Bukti Bayar" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                <input type="file" name="nonroutine_expenses_file[]" id="" class="nonroutine_expenses_file d-none">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="drml-btn-primary-xs drml-border-radius-4 nonroutine_expenses_file_button"><i class="drml-icon-upload-white"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-right py-2">
          <a id="deleteNonroutineExpenses" class="btn btn-link text-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link drml-text-primary drml-spacing-1 shadow-none font-weight-bold" id="addMoreNonroutineExpenses" style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg mr-2"></i>Tambah Pinjaman</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot set a file upload value for obvious security reasons

Comment: the nonroutine_expenses_file_name is not the input type=fille, but its a type=text, 
 my post already updated

Comment: I do not speak Indonesian. Can you make another image showing the relationship between file name and the cloned row?

Comment: Hi, that's because `var var_this = $(this);` is not referring current element because its outside `$(this).on('change', function() {..` put it inside event handler that should work fine.

Comment: @mplungjan i've added another image in my updated post :)

Comment: @Swati hi swati, its you again.. thank for reply^^^, but its still not working, i've changed my code like : $(this).parent().parent().find('.nonroutine_expenses_file_name').val(var_filename);

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5zyudLjx/) working fiddle .Let me know this is what you want to do .

Comment: @Swati ok!! wait :)

Comment: @Swati eh, how can its work in https://jsfiddle.net/5zyudLjx/ but not working in my project T_T

Comment: `newRow.find("input").val("");` will clear all new inputs

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your reply!!!! its already done "Can you make another image showing the relationship between file name and the cloned row?" your comment make me think that my wrong is on the button upload (not the filename function)

Comment: @Swati thanks swatiiiii, you help me twice, your comment "Hi, that's because var var_this = $(this); is not referring current element because its outside $(this).on('change', function() {.. put it inside event handler that should work fine." its true, but i try to put that code, but i put it in the wrong place which the right place is reffer to MPLUNGJAN comment